# Unable to marshal protobuf structs

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, marshalling, go-gin

I have created my proto file for my structs, and I would like to Marshal them for passing it to my front.
Two questions then:

- Could/should I marshal my structs for my front end (Angular, vue, react, ...) or I am mandatory to work with JSON on API return?
- I tried to Marshal them but I still have an issue : `cannot use message (variable of type *structs.BasicAuth) as proto.Message value in argument to proto.Marshal: missing method ProtoMessage`

Here is my code for illustrating. Could you help me to fix it please?

```
package routes

import (
    "fmt"

    "project/api/structs"
    "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func SetupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    r := gin.Default()
    v1 := r.Group("/v1")

    auth := v1.Group("/auth")
    {
        auth.POST("/basic", computeBasicAuth).Use(checkBasicAuthParameters())
        // Not the right place for the following Marshal code, just for PoC
        message := &structs.BasicAuth{
            Username: "Foo",
            Password: "Bar",
        }
        data, _ := proto.Marshal(message)
    }
    return r
}
```

```
package structs

type BasicAuth struct {
    Username string
    Password string
}
```

```
syntax = "proto3";
package structs;

message BasicAuth {
    string Username = 1;
    string Password = 2;
}
```

```
// Code generated by protoc-gen-go. DO NOT EDIT.
// source: proto/structs/structs.proto

package structs

import (
    fmt "fmt"
    proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
    math "math"
)

// Reference imports to suppress errors if they are not otherwise used.
var _ = proto.Marshal
var _ = fmt.Errorf
var _ = math.Inf

// This is a compile-time assertion to ensure that this generated file
// is compatible with the proto package it is being compiled against.
// A compilation error at this line likely means your copy of the
// proto package needs to be updated.
const _ = proto.ProtoPackageIsVersion3 // please upgrade the proto package

type BasicAuth struct {
    Username             string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=Username,proto3" json:"Username,omitempty"`
    Password             string   `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=Password,proto3" json:"Password,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}

func (m *BasicAuth) Reset()         { *m = BasicAuth{} }
func (m *BasicAuth) String() string { return proto.CompactTextString(m) }
func (*BasicAuth) ProtoMessage()    {}
func (*BasicAuth) Descriptor() ([]byte, []int) {
    return fileDescriptor_3e35c36397ab84cd, []int{0}
}

func (m *BasicAuth) XXX_Unmarshal(b []byte) error {
    return xxx_messageInfo_BasicAuth.Unmarshal(m, b)
}
func (m *BasicAuth) XXX_Marshal(b []byte, deterministic bool) ([]byte, error) {
    return xxx_messageInfo_BasicAuth.Marshal(b, m, deterministic)
}
func (m *BasicAuth) XXX_Merge(src proto.Message) {
    xxx_messageInfo_BasicAuth.Merge(m, src)
}
func (m *BasicAuth) XXX_Size() int {
    return xxx_messageInfo_BasicAuth.Size(m)
}
func (m *BasicAuth) XXX_DiscardUnknown() {
    xxx_messageInfo_BasicAuth.DiscardUnknown(m)
}

var xxx_messageInfo_BasicAuth proto.InternalMessageInfo

func (m *BasicAuth) GetUsername() string {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Username
    }
    return ""
}

func (m *BasicAuth) GetPassword() string {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Password
    }
    return ""
}

func init() {
    proto.RegisterType((*BasicAuth)(nil), "structs.BasicAuth")
}

func init() { proto.RegisterFile("proto/structs/structs.proto", fileDescriptor_3e35c36397ab84cd) }

var fileDescriptor_3e35c36397ab84cd = []byte{
    // 123 bytes of a gzipped FileDescriptorProto
    0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xff, 0xe2, 0x92, 0x2e, 0x28, 0xca, 0x2f,
    0xc9, 0xd7, 0x2f, 0x2e, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x4d, 0x2e, 0x29, 0x86, 0xd1, 0x7a, 0x60, 0x51, 0x21, 0x76,
    0x28, 0x57, 0xc9, 0x99, 0x8b, 0xd3, 0x29, 0xb1, 0x38, 0x33, 0xd9, 0xb1, 0xb4, 0x24, 0x43, 0x48,
    0x8a, 0x8b, 0x23, 0xb4, 0x38, 0xb5, 0x28, 0x2f, 0x31, 0x37, 0x55, 0x82, 0x51, 0x81, 0x51, 0x83,
    0x33, 0x08, 0xce, 0x07, 0xc9, 0x05, 0x24, 0x16, 0x17, 0x97, 0xe7, 0x17, 0xa5, 0x48, 0x30, 0x41,
    0xe4, 0x60, 0x7c, 0x25, 0x79, 0x2e, 0x76, 0xaf, 0xf0, 0x10, 0xb0, 0x11, 0x22, 0x5c, 0xac, 0x21,
    0xf9, 0xd9, 0xa9, 0x79, 0x50, 0xfd, 0x10, 0x4e, 0x12, 0x1b, 0xd8, 0x56, 0x63, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x5f, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0x6b, 0x94, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
}
```

Comment: You need to use the definition of `BasicAuth` from the generated file.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't get the point. How to use the structs from generated file? I thought it is automatically mapped between my own strict and the generated one. I thought I just had to call my own struct

Comment: You should be importing the generated file and using the definition of `BasicAuth` in there. That struct has the necessary methods defined on it for protobuf operations to work. The error that you got is saying that the version of `BasicAuth` that you passed to `proto.Marshal` doesn't have the `ProtoMessage` method defined on it. You'll notice that the generated file does define that method and others which are necessary for performing protobuf operations.

Comment: Oh you made my day bro ! Thank you very much !